# Move part of map in R's ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I am trying to map some data in R using ggmap. When I get the map it looks something like this.

```
cen <- geocode('Danmark')
center <- as.numeric(cen)
map <- get_googlemap(center = center, zoom = 6,
                     size = c(640, 640), scale = 2, region="dk",crop = TRUE,color="bw")
ggmap(map) #+ geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size=antal), data=df, colour="darkred")
```

[image: danish map]

The problem is that the island of Bornholm is located to the far east of Denmark. This makes the map very large. To increase the space usage I would like to move Bornholm to the upper right corner. Something like this

[image: danish map]

How can I do this in ggmap and still overlay data?

Comment: Do you know this blog entry? It seems like the grid package is always a good idea in this case - http://r-nold.blogspot.de/2014/06/creating-inset-map-with-ggplot2.html

Comment: Looks right. Gonna try it out soon. thanks a lot.